# Inserting set of rows for every ID in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

this is an initial table (this is just a part of a larger table where Article ID's can vary), database is MS Sql.

```
-----------------------------------
|ArticleID |     GroupID          |
-----------------------------------
|      1   |        NULL          |
-----------------------------------
|      2   |        NULL          | 
-----------------------------------
|      3   |        NULL          |
-----------------------------------
|      4   |        NULL          | 
-----------------------------------
```

Set of rows that should be entered for each ArticleID looks something like this:

```
------------------------
|      GroupID         |
------------------------
|         A            |
------------------------
|         B            | 
------------------------
|         C            |
------------------------
|         D            | 
------------------------
```

Result table should look something like this:

```
-----------------------------------
|ArticleID |     GroupID          |
-----------------------------------
|      1   |        NULL          |
-----------------------------------
|      1   |         A            | 
-----------------------------------
|      1   |         B            |
-----------------------------------
|      1   |         C            | 
-----------------------------------
|      1   |         D            | 
-----------------------------------
|      2   |        NULL          |
-----------------------------------
|      2   |         A            | 
-----------------------------------
|      2   |         B            |
-----------------------------------
|      2   |         C            | 
-----------------------------------
|      2   |         D            | 
-----------------------------------
|      3   |        NULL          |
-----------------------------------
|      3   |         A            | 
-----------------------------------
|      3   |         B            |
-----------------------------------
|      3   |         C            | 
-----------------------------------
|      3   |         D            | 
-----------------------------------
|      4   |        NULL          |
-----------------------------------
|      4   |         A            | 
-----------------------------------
|      4   |         B            |
-----------------------------------
|      4   |         C            | 
-----------------------------------
|      4   |         D            | 
-----------------------------------
```

Any suggestion how to insert it efficiently?
Thanks a lot for you suggestion.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *cross join* between two sets.

```
with a as (
  select * from(values (1),(2),(3),(4))v(ArticleId)
), g as (
 select * from(values (null),('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'))v(GroupId)
)
select *
from a cross join g;
```

To insert into the original table you could do:

```
with g as (select * from(values('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'))v(GroupId))
insert into t
select t.ArticleId, g.GroupId
from t cross join g;
```

See [Example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=784aea75846eb014394417522fbed114)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Insert with cross join will do the job just fine.